# Sorting and printing a text file in Python idle

Tags: python, file, sorting

- I have a text file with 2 columns of data (student name and score) separated by a ':' (see below)
- I would like the user to be able to sort the text file alphabetically via name and print out this sorted data as well as their highest corresponding score to the IDLE
- I would also like to give the user the option to sort the scores from highest to lowest and print out this along with their names
- Finally I would like to give them to option to sort and print the data from highest to lowest based on the average score of each student.

**Text file**

```
Alex:2
Steve:3
Andy:4
Wallace:6
Andy:3
Andy:5
Dan:1
Dan:0
Steve:3
```

I attempted to add the names to a list and then doing a sort on the numerical data but I had no luck.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a question about school homework?

Comment: No. Just trying to teach myself python

Comment: Your question is too general. At the very least narrow down what you're trying to do and add a sample of the code you wrote in an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started:

You need to associate the names and the scores.  A tuple like (name, score) would work for this.  So, you can process the file like this:

```
gradebook = list()
with open('scores.txt') as infile:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split(':').rstrip()
        gradebook.append((line[0], line[1]))
```

Now you can sort the gradebook by either column.  (Look up the built-sort)

When you want to work with the averages, I think you'll find the easiest way to go about it is with a dict.